# Python-Add or remove letters at a specific location

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one question:

If I have something like

`['a', 'o', 'r', 'x', ' ', 's', 'n', ' ', 'k', 'p', 'l', 'q', 't']`

How can I add for example 3 letters generated using random.choice() before and after every string in this list?

Comment: what have you tried to do before asking? what is the expected output? what are you passing to `random.choice()`? after `'a'` should there be 3 or 6 characters

Comment: Is the same with what you have

Comment: And edit your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want it to be like 
['n','k','b','A','s','p','i','O', 'r', 'x', ' ', 's', 'n', ' ', 'k', 'p', 'l', 'q', 't']

Comment: only around the first letter? and capitalize the first 2 elements? where did b and i come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following:

- generate a string containing all the letters
- use `ranodm.sample()` instead of `random.choice()` to generate a list of 3 random letters, which you then should `join()`
- return an in-place list with the new elements

It'd look like this:

```
import string
import random


def add_str(lst):
    _letters = string.ascii_letters
    return [''.join(random.sample(set(_letters), 3)) + letter + ''.join(random.sample(set(_letters), 3))
            for letter in lst]


print(add_str(['a', 'o', 'r', 'x', ' ', 's', 'n', ' ', 'k', 'p', 'l', 'q', 't']))

> ['FUsaeNZ', 'pASoiTI', 'XfbrUXe', 'ZyKxhSs', 'lIJ blk', 'bJXseAI', 'uFcnUeQ', 'KRd wfF', 'VyPkjvq', 'CbwpCro', 'QOTlNfi', 'UNuqRDe', 'hEjtnIv']
```

*I supposed you want different letters at the beginning and the end of each letter from the string. If you need them to be the same, you can handle it. Since you didn't provide any example, I answered your exact question and what I understood from it. If you need something else (and it looks like it's the case from the comments), you have where to start from anyway*

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But is there any way to unite the output into 1 string?

Comment: Use: `print(''.join(add_str(['a', 'o', 'r', 'x', ' ', 's', 'n', ' ', 'k', 'p', 'l', 'q', 't'])))`

Comment: Ok, last question: What should I do for opposite thing, when I want to remove those additional characters?

Comment: I mean when I have something like ['FUsaeNZpASoiTIXfbrUXeZyKxhSslIJ blkbJXseAIuFcnUeQKRd JfF'VyPkjvqCbwpCroQOTlNfiUNuqRDehEjtnIv'] how can I make it to delete everything except (['a', 'o', 'r', 'x', ' ', 's', 'n', ' ', 'k', 'p', 'l', 'q', 't'] and btw I dont need something that will say delete everything except this list,i want it to be usable on input.Sorry its a little bit complicated